# Drools: how to apply rules on all elements in a List and find a subset elements that satisfies given conditions

Tags: list, loops, drools

I am relatively newbie to drools and I am pulling my hair to achieve the following scenario.

I have a list of dates, let's say 10 dates. Now, I have to apply a set of rules among these elements to find matching set of 4 dates that satisfies all rules.

Assuming following are the rules. How do I iterate this in drools and find the four dates amongst provided 10 dates.

```
date2> date1 + (6W - 4D)
date3> date2 + (4W - 4D)
date4 > date3 + (6M - 4D)
date4 > date1 + (4Y - 4D)
```

Comment: Thanks to Esteban Aliverti, I am able to achieve this, but if I have to report a failure reason . Lets say rule can be false for any of reason on $d1 , $ d2, $d3 or $d4. If I want to report or log for which scenario it failed, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a helper class who knows how to do arithmetic with dates.

```
public class Helper {
    public static Date calculate(Date source, String expression) {
        //Do the magic
    }  
}
```

You can then use this helper class in your rules as follows:

```
rule "Find subset"
when
  $d1: Date()
  $d2: Date(this > Helper.calculate($d1, "6W-4D"))
  $d3: Date(this > Helper.calculate($d2, "4W-4D"))
  $d4: Date(
    this > Helper.calculate($d1, "4Y-4D"), 
    this > Helper.calculate($d3, "6M-4D")
  )
then
  //Do whatever you need 
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you Esteban, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Esteban Aliverti,  I have another complication, its more of a followup on previous case. If I have to report a failure reason . Lets say rule can be false for any of reason on $d1 , $ d2, $d3 or $d4. If I want to report or log for which scenario it failed, how do I do that?

Comment: There is no way to do that in Drools. You will need to explicitly write rules for each of the failing scenarios.

Comment: I agree, there is no If else type of option in Drools to achieve this. However, in my case there will be multiple sets of rules lets say. 
Rule1 ( with multiple conditions on dates d1,d2,d3.)  Rule2(with different condition of d1, d2, d3) and Rule3(with different conditions on them.). Now if I want to provide list of dates against all these rules and obtain reason for failure how do I do that. I don't think writing a not case for each time would be a ideal solution to mycase.